# Using R, how can I re-order a swimmers plot so that the horizontal bars are arranged by ID number?

Tags: r

I have attempted searching for 'swimmers' and 'reorder' in the sub but didn't come across a solution that I could understand and utilize.

I have the following data frame, imported from Excel as a csv file.
[image of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjRI8.png)

And am using this version of R: 2021.09.1 Build 372

And the following code to generate the swimmers plot:
[image of my terminal, showing libraries, code, and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWRJh.png)

This yields the following plot:
[Swimmers Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdfiV.png)

I would like to re-order the plot so that the horizontal bars are arranged in order of increasing ID number (1, 2, 3, 4... down to 10).

I was following the guide [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swimplot/vignettes/Introduction.to.swimplot.html#modifying-the-order-and-colours-of-the-bars) in order to try to make the plot. As you can see from my code image, using 'reorder' or 'id_order' doesn't seem to be working. I am a complete beginner in R and coding, but I suspect the issue lies in something being interpreted as.character rather than as.numeric but wondering how I can fix this.

Any assistance is sincerely appreciated. I apologize for the fundamental nature of my lack of knowledge. Have tried looking it up various ways and trying suggestions online, but without success.

---

**I haven't the foggiest idea why this didn't work when I tried it earlier, but using the following argument was successful for me:
id_order=c('10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1')**

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `ggplot2`

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(ID), y = Day, fill=Stage))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Stage = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C"), Day = c(14L, 18L, 21L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 3L, 
16L, 24L, 25L, 0L, 10L, 17L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 32L, 13L, 13L, 
22L, 3L, 9L, 22L, 0L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, TarJae!